# Copy problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: copy

Whenever I am copying a file, especially video files, to any external USB drive the copy dialog halts at the end of the file and takes a long time to finish the copy.

If there are multiple files then the copy halts for 2-3 minutes after which next file gets started and same happens at the end of the next file.

What should I do to solve this problem?